# How can I change Codeblocks theme (like Windows white theme) on Kali Linux 2020.2?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, themes, code-blocks

How can I change Codeblocks theme like Windows white theme on Kali Linux 2020.2? Codeblocks 20.3 and Kali Linux 2020.2. The theme of Codeblocks is black and editor theme is white. I want white theme for whole environment like in Windows.

Screenshot of current theme in Code::Blocks: [image: Screenshot of current theme in Code::Blocks]

Comment: facing the same issue. Could you find a fix?

Comment: @ayush7ad6 Yes. I got the solution. Have a look on the answer section. I already have answered it.

Comment: that's not a solution since it will change the theme for each application.

Comment: vv supposed to be 'the' answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to **settings > appearance** and select **windows-10** under **style** section. Now open Codeblocks and you will find an interface like Windows 10 Codeblocks interface. You can also select **Kali-Light**. It will do same.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**
You can create a custom `.desktop` file of the application you want to change the theme of. And edit it to have a specific theme. So the next time you run that application it will have the specified theme.
Also, this method will not change any other applications' theme.

For a comprehensive explanation you can visit: https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio

Comment: Please do not only link to other Stack Exchange sites but quote the most important parts of the answer you are referring to.

Comment: noted @DarkDiamond